# Fine Uploader working in every browser except IE

Tags: fine-uploader

I'll post my Javascript below. It works perfectly for all browsers but not at all in IE 8 or IE 9. No errors, it just doesn't work.  I guess the good news is that I can tell exactly where it breaks (see below) but I don't know why or how to fix it.

My HTML is simple. It's just a test page for a much larger project that I'm working on. I have 6 file input boxes in a simple form on the page. What I'm trying to do is to grab those input fields, discard any that are empty, and submit the files (pictures) one-by-one to the server. I know there are more elegant ways to send pictures but for the site I'm working on this is the best way to do it.

I'm using the server-side PHP code provided with the software.  It's unchanged.

I'll admit up front that I'm self-taught and Javascript is a weak point for me. I'm not an idiot but I'm new to Javascript.

The code works flawlessly in all browsers except IE. The page loads, the document.ready() code runs and the Fine Uploader DIV is placed on the page. The problem comes when I hit the submit button. I tracked the problem down to the line

```
manualUploader.fineUploader('addFiles', current[0].files[0]);
```

For some reason running that line of code breaks my script, the submit goes on through without processing any of the rest of the code and completely ignores the 'return false;' statement that should prevent the submission. As far as I can tell, it doesn't throw any errors.  Why would IE treat that code any differently than all of the other browsers? Any help would be appreciated.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var numFiles = 0;
        var numUploaded = 0;

        var manualUploader = $('#sandbox').fineUploader({
            request: {
                endpoint: '../../Processing/ajax_uploader.php'
            },
            autoUpload: false,
            debug: true,
            maxConnections: 1
        }).on('complete', function(event, id, name, responseJSON){
                numUploaded++;              
                var tempField = $('#' + 'pic' + (id + 1)).parent();
                tempField = tempField.parent();
                tempField.remove();
                $('#frmNewProperty').append('<input type="hidden" name="hiddenPic' + id + '" value="' + name + '" />');
                if (numUploaded == numFiles){
                    $('form#frmNewProperty').submit();
                }
        });         

    $('#subButton').click(function() {
        var fields = $('.fileBox');
        $.each(fields, function(){
            var current = $(this).find('.outgoing');
            var dat = current.val();
            if (dat != ''){
                manualUploader.fineUploader('addFiles', current[0].files[0]);
                numFiles++;
            }
        });
        manualUploader.fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles');   
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code depends on File API support.  The line you referenced expects a `files` property to be present (and contain a `FileList` for a value) on the input element's host object.  This is only true if the File API is supported.  IE9 and older do not support the File API.  For those browsers, you will need to pass the input element itself to the `addFiles` API function.

Comment: Thank you so much.  That makes perfect sense.

Comment: Sorry, Nichlous I did not understand your solution. Please help me out because I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @Napster open up a new thread that shows your code, lists any console errors, and clearly explain your issues.

Comment: Ya, that could be more comfortable. Thanks for the reply. Let me create new ticket for that.

Comment: @RayNicholus : Please have a look at this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807899/fineuploader-spree-image-upload-fails-from-ie-browser

Answer (score 1):

I see that this link came back to life a few days ago so I thought I'd post the little snippet of code that I had to add just in case anybody else stumbles across this thread and finds it helpful.

Thanks again to RayNicholus for the pointer.  He was dead-on and saved me hours (or days most likely) of research.

For IE9 and earlier you have to replace the following line:

```
manualUploader.fineUploader('addFiles', current[0].files[0]);
```

with something like:

```
manualUploader.fineUploader('addFiles', current);
```

Comment: Actually, you don't have to do this anymore, as of version 3.6.  You can now pass the input element regardless of the browser.  I effectively normalized the expected parameters of the `addFiles` API method in 3.6.  See case [#749](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/749) for more details.